# Dispersion of housing prices in Hsieh And Moretti (2018)

Tags: macroeconomics, labor-economics

I have been reading  'Housing Constraints and Spatial Misallocation', by Moretti and Hsieh, AEJ Macro 2018, https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/mac.20170388
In their equation (7), they derive a formula for aggregate output which is a function of $\frac{Q}{Qi}$, where $Q_i$ is the local housing price and Q is the weighted average.

$$
Y=\left(\frac{\eta}{R}\right)^{\frac{\eta}{1-\eta}}\left[\sum_i\left(A_i \cdot\left[\frac{\bar{Q}}{Q_i}\right]^{1-\eta}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha-\eta}} \cdot T_i\right]^{\frac{1-\alpha-\eta}{1-\eta}},
$$
where $Q_i \equiv P_i^\beta / Z_i$ is the ratio of the housing price $P_i$ to local amenities $Z_i, \bar{Q} \equiv \sum_i L_i Q_i$ is the employment-weighted average of $Q_i$ across all cities, and the housing price is determined by equation (4).

Then they say:
'In what follows, for brevity we will refer to $Q_i \equiv P_i^\beta / Z_i$ as the "local price," by which we mean the ratio of housing prices to amenities. Aggregate output is a power mean of local TFP weighted by the inverse of the local price in the city relative to the average in all cities. Importantly, since $(1-\eta) /(1-\alpha-\eta)>1$, a mean preserving spread of local prices lowers aggregate output. The aggregate effect of the dispersion in local prices is increasing in the labor share $\alpha$.'

If you look at the formula, however, it looks to me like the reverse should be true. If I interpret local prices as defined in the text to be just $Q_i$, that is a convex function in $Q_i$, and so we get that taking a mean preserving spread increases the total value. This also holds true for some numerical examples I made for myself.
I had a doubt if the mps had to be done for $Q$ preserved, that is, accounting for different weights, so I did more than one try, adjusting the weights in the same direction of the Qs, but it still failed. I am puzzled cause the authors state this as obvious.
Thanks if anybody can help.